# How do you pass a Managed Bean of different type to a composite for reuse?

Tags: jsf-2, managed-bean, composite-component

I'm creating an inline text editor. I've written the code to edit one single `h:ouputText` field (`h:inputHidden`). Works. Thus, I thought I create a composite (widget), that I can call for every field I want to update. Of course, those fields refer to a managed bean in my case, that is the PubController MB.

```
<composite:interface name="inlineEditor">
    <composite:attribute name="attrOfMb" required="true"
        type="java.lang.String" />
    <composite:attribute name="pubController" required="true" type="com.playground.webapp.controller.PubController"/>
</composite:interface>
```

Now, I have the following tasks to accomplish:

1. pass the MB to the composite (done).
2. in the composite, create the div and the hidden input field with id of the MB attribute.

Challenge where I struggle:

- How do I "bind" an attribute of the passed PubController to the hidden input field? #{cc.attrs.pubController.title}? Well, it should not always be the same attribute. The attribute should be chosen by what has been passed in the interface attribute `attrOfMb`.
- In other cases, its not necessariley PubController. Might be another MB. My initial thought was to define the interface type to `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`. On the other hand, how could you then "bind" the passed MB to the input hidden field (respectively vice-versa).

Is there a JSF-Pattern on how you accomplish these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going in the wrong path as to designing the composite. You should bind a bean *property*, not a whole bean.

I.e. you should not have

```
<my:composite bean="#{bean}" />
```

but you should have

```
<my:composite value="#{bean.value}" title="#{bean.title}" />
```

Once you fix that problem, then you can easily reuse it on any backing bean. Please note that this is also the way how standard JSF `<h:xxx>` components work. If you worry about about "too many" attributes for some unclear reason, then just create a reusable model class which in turn can be a property of the backing bean.

```
<my:composite data="#{bean.data}" />
```

This way you can use it further in the composite as `#{cc.attrs.data.value}`, `#{cc.attrs.data.title}`, etc.

If you really, *really* need to bind a whole bean, then I'd question if a tag file or maybe an include file isn't a better solution for whatever functional requirement you've had in mind. A composite component should really represent a component with a *single* responsibility and a *single* point of model value binding.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)

Comment: Making total sense. Thank you BalusC.

Comment: If the bean property is declared as attribute of the composite, how could I every bind to the MB (backing bean)?

The reason why I'm asking is because, this property must updated the backings bean's property value on-the-fly while changed. Is EL so mighty to understand that this passed property is still a part of the backing bean and is to update as soon a user changed the value?

Comment: ok. I tested. The backing bean property, which is passed does not require any type declaration in the interface tag.